# Multiple queue workers in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I've specified numprocs as 8 in the supervisor configuration. But everytime I dispatch a job, it basically processes the same job 8 times:

```
[2017-08-14 02:00:11] Processed: App\Jobs\UpdateOrders
[2017-08-14 03:00:09] Processed: App\Jobs\UpdateOrders
[2017-08-14 04:00:07] Processed: App\Jobs\UpdateOrders
[2017-08-14 05:00:06] Processed: App\Jobs\UpdateOrders
[2017-08-14 06:00:10] Processed: App\Jobs\UpdateOrders
[2017-08-14 07:00:08] Processed: App\Jobs\UpdateOrders
[2017-08-14 08:00:09] Processed: App\Jobs\UpdateOrders
[2017-08-14 09:06:39] Processed: App\Jobs\UpdateOrders
```

Here's what my supervisor config looks like:

```
[program:product-manager]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php artisan queue:listen
numprocs=8
autostart=true
autorestart=true
directory=/var/www/html
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/logs/product-manager.log
```

How do I set it so that it only uses one worker if I've only dispatched one job. Or utilize all 8 workers if I dispatched 8 jobs. Is that the way it works? Am I having a wrong idea about how multiple workers in laravel queue works? All I really want is to have each worker work on a separate job that I dispatched.

Comment: How is your queue configured?  Are you using the database (via `artisan queue:listen`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked if the OP can be updated with a clarification as to the queue configuration.  This answer may be proven wrong subject to that update.

Your supervisor configuration is spawning multiple workers (using the Laravel built-in worker, which isn't super scalable or necessarily "production ready", but fine for development and testing) who are all trying to consume from a queue (which I'm guessing is probably a database table).

It's the queue's responsibility (for example Amazon SQS or AMQP etc) to ensure that a message on the queue is only delivered (consumed) **once**.  I expect you're using a queue which doesn't enforce that (like the database), and multiple workers are consuming the same message together.  (A kind of [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).)

Possibly *my* understanding of how the database and `artisan` consumer works is wrong - in which case I trust I'll be down voted.  That'd be where I'd start looking though.

Comment: yeah, I'm using the database. Laravel supports Beanstalkd, IronMQ, Amazon SQS, Redis. Can I use one of these to ensure that each worker only processes a job once? Which one do you recommend?

Comment: Yeah, so *if* my (educated) guess as to the problem is correct - any of those will work.  Amazon SQS works (from my experience) an absolute dream if you're running in production on AWS.  (I used this binding: https://github.com/dusterio/laravel-aws-worker)  If you're running in `homestead`, then `beanstalkd` comes pre-installed (I'm not sure if it's pre-configured though).  Any of them will ensure that messages are only consumed the once.  I've personally used RabbitMQ for non-AWS deployments in the past, but ya-know, they're much-and-much the same.  Are you looking for production or dev?

Comment: I don't really want to spend any money on the queue so I guess I'll just stick with beanstalkd or redis. I'm looking to use it on production. You mentioned Laravel's built-in worker isn't really production-ready, so what do you recommend for me to use?

Comment: It'd depend on your production platform.  If you've got a virtual-private-server or dedicated tin which you're looking after yourself, I'd simply look to see if beanstalkd or IronMQ are supported by your Linux distribution and pick based on what you feel comfortable with (I've no experience to suggest which will be better).  You might find looking at ServerFault.com useful to gain some insights there.  The `artisan` command (with a database queue) is more a "proof of concept" and isn't designed for reliability or efficiency, which is why I wouldn't use it *in production*.

Comment: (cont.) - but the point of Laravel's queueing is to *abstract* the queue platform away.  So you write your code once, then deploy on whatever infrastructure you have.  So if you in the future deploy on AWS or you're deploying on a CPanel instance which comes with Redis out of the box - you can opt to use those with little more than a few changes to a config file.  My rule of thumb is *always use whatever comes most supported and most simply configured on the target platform* - which may be different between dev, QA and production.